# nextjs taking me to a new page with links

Tags: reactjs, next.js, anchor

Right now I'm trying to make it so that when I click on the text on the navbar it'll scroll down to the section in nextjs. I have the following code:

```
 <Link href="#About">About</Link>
 <Link href="#Sponsors">Sponsors</Link>
 <Link href="#FAQ">FAQ</Link>
```

This is the navbar, when I click about sponsors for example i want to go down to the page to sponsors
[image: navbar]

Where about, sponsors, and faq are sections on the page as you can see here:
[image: sponsors section]

So this is working but it OPENS A NEW TAB which I don't want. I want it to scroll down to where sponsors is.

Some information:
Sponsor
About
and FAQ are their own components that I want to scroll to

Answer (score 0):

you need to have all your Sponsors, About, FAQ components in for example "home.jsx"
and they must have the id of "Sponsors", "About", "FAQ"
now you can use

```
<a href="#Sponsors"/>
<a href="#About"/>
<a href="#FAQ"/>
```

to make the page to scroll to the section you want.
but if you want to render each component in different url you cannot use this method and you must use nextjs `<Link>` to go to the other page like

```
http://localhost:3000/Sponsors
http://localhost:3000/Sponsors
http://localhost:3000/Sponsors
```